# Get SQL data in javasscript

Tags: javascript, sql

i have this script

I want to select the images from the database can somebody help me?
Or give me an example of a script so I can see how it's done

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
if (document.images) {
image1 = new Image
image2 = new Image

image1.src = "/images/image01.jpg"
image2.src = "/images/image02.jpg"

}
</SCRIPT>

<p><a href="#"
onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image2.src" 
onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image2.src">text 1</a>  <br />
<a href="#"
onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image1.src"
onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image1.src">text 2</a></p>
<img src="/images/image01.jpg" name="imagename" border="0" />
```

Comment: you're going to need to factor in a server-side language (PHP, ASP.NET, etc) to send requests before you can pull data from SQL (which DBMS are you using?)

Comment: @mdmullinax, not necessarily. He just needs some interface available on public port. Preferably HTTP based.

Answer (score 1):

you could use jQuery.Ajax to make a call to a web function.

see this for the  [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

and this for the [web service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service) if you are using c#

i am not familiar with other languages except microsoft based ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jQuery or Ajax to make your thing happen. I don't think it is possible with  javascript.

With jQuery u can have a separate file where you write your server side language and queries.

With

```
$.post(url, {params, ..}, function (Result) { alert(Result will have the location of your image );} );
```